# v-model inside vue draggable lost focus after keypress?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, v-model, vuedraggable

I have installed, `"vuedraggable": "^4.1.0",`

Works very well, and orders well, but inputs lost focus on any keypress action with v-model.
The problem is definitely with vuedraggable and v-model.

```
<draggable
              :list="widgets"
              item-key="name"
              class="list-group"
              ghost-class="ghost"
              @update="saveUpdatedOrder"
            >
....
<el-input
   v-model="element.name"
   class="add-new-item__title"
   placeholder="Title"></el-input>
```

When I want to change `element.name` value, this input loses focus, so after every character I need to touch input again and put focus on him, to be able to continue charging text.

Any idea?

Comment: Hey, did you check it because its focus is working fine- https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused because you use the `element.name` in the input field and as the key for vue-draggable. Since vue is keeping track of DOM-elements [by its key](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key) in a v-for loop, I think changing the name will make vue to delete the DOM element and create a new one, with the new key as identifier. That is why it looks like the input is loosing focus, while it actually is another input element.

Changing `item-key="name"` to another **unique** property of the widget object, like title or id, will solve the problem. Since you did not provide the widgets array, I cannot be clear on what would be a usable property.